# Como salvar os dados retirando os caracteres do mask, utilizando laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel

Oi, estou utilizando o Laravel, e quero salvar os dados após feito um cálculo.
Estou utilizando o plugin JQuery Mask para facilitar o entendimento do usuário.
Porém, não tenho ideia de como filtrar os dados da mask para salvar as informações.  Inclusive já tenho uma função javascript para tirar os dados do mask, para fazer um cálculo. Será que tem como pegar os dados do javascript direto pelo controlador do Laravel? Por favor, me ajudem :)

O erro (porque está pegando os dados do mask (R$, %):

[image: erro]

Alguns códigos:

View:

```
<form action="/produtos" method="POST">
                    @csrf           
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <label>Custo 1:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-group" id="custo1" name="custo1" onkeyup="calcular();">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <label>IPI:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-group" id="perc_ipi" name="perc_ipi" onkeyup="calcular();"><br><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <label>ST:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-group" id="perc_st" name="perc_st" onkeyup="calcular();">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <label>Outros:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-group" id="perc_outros" name="perc_outros" onkeyup="calcular();"><br><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <label>Frete:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-group" id="perc_frete" name="perc_frete" onkeyup="calcular();">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <label>FCPST:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-group" id="perc_fcpst" name="perc_fcpst" onkeyup="calcular();"><br><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <label>STUF:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-group" id="perc_stuf" name="perc_stuf" onkeyup="calcular();">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <label>Desconto:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-group" id="perc_desc" name="perc_desc" onkeyup="calcular();"><br><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <label>Custo 2:</label>
                            <span type="text" class="form-group" id="custo2" name="custo2"></span><br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block col-4" type="submit">Salvar</button>
                </form>
```

JS:

```
//Função para retornar apenas os números
    function somenteNumero(n){
       n = n.replace(/[^\d,]/g,'')
       .replace(",", '.');
       return +n; 
    }

        //Função para calcular custo2
    function calcular() {           
        var custo1 = somenteNumero(document.getElementById('custo1').value);
        var calcIPI1 = somenteNumero(document.getElementById('perc_ipi').value);
        var calcST1 = somenteNumero(document.getElementById('perc_st').value);
        var calcOutros1 = somenteNumero(document.getElementById('perc_outros').value);
        var calcFrete1 = somenteNumero(document.getElementById('perc_frete').value);
        var calcFCPST1 = somenteNumero(document.getElementById('perc_fcpst').value);
        var calcSTUF1 = somenteNumero(document.getElementById('perc_stuf').value);
        var calcDesconto1 = somenteNumero(document.getElementById('perc_desc').value);
        var elemResult = document.getElementById("custo2");


        //Fórmulas das percentagens
        calcIPI2 = custo1 * calcIPI1 / 100 + custo1;
        calcST2 = custo1 * calcST1 / 100;
        calcOutros2 = custo1 * calcOutros1 / 100;
        calcFrete2 = custo1 * calcFrete1 / 100;
        calcFCPST2 = custo1 * calcFCPST1 / 100;
        calcSTUF2 = custo1 * calcSTUF1 / 100;

        //Gerando o custo 2.
        custo2 = calcIPI2 + calcST2 + calcOutros2 + calcFrete2 + calcFCPST2 + calcSTUF2;

        custo2 = custo2 - custo1 * calcDesconto1 / 100;

        elemResult.innerText = custo2.toLocaleString("pt-BR", { style: "currency" , currency:"BRL"});

        }

        //JQuery Maskmoney
        $(function() {
          $('#custo1').maskMoney({ prefix: 'R$  ', reverse: 'false', decimal: ',', thousands: '.', precision: 2 });
        })

        $(function() {
          $('#venda').maskMoney({ prefix: 'R$  ', reverse: 'false', decimal: ',', thousands: '.', precision: 2 });
        })

        //JQuery Mask

        $('#perc_ipi').mask('##0,00%', {reverse: true});

        $("#perc_frete").mask('##0,00%', {reverse: true});

        $("#perc_outros").mask('##0,00%', {reverse: true});

        $("#perc_st").mask('##0,00%', {reverse: true});

        $("#perc_fcpst").mask('##0,00%', {reverse: true});

        $("#perc_stuf").mask('##0,00%', {reverse: true});

        $("#perc_desc").mask('##0,00%', {reverse: true});

        $("#custo2").mask("999.999.990,00", {reverse: true});

        $("#venda").mask("999.999.990,00", {reverse: true});
```

Controlador:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $produto = new Produto();
    $produto->custo1 = $request->input('custo1');
    $produto->perc_ipi = $request->input('perc_ipi');
    $produto->perc_frete = $request->input('perc_frete');
    $produto->perc_outros = $request->input('perc_outros');
    $produto->perc_st = $request->input('perc_st');
    $produto->perc_fcpst = $request->input('perc_fcpst');
    $produto->perc_stuf = $request->input('perc_stuf');
    $produto->perc_desc = $request->input('perc_desc');
    $produto->custo2 = $request->input('custo2');

    $produto->save();
    return redirect('/produtos');
}
```

Comment: Faça envio por ajax o jquery mask tem uma função que tira o mask olha doc dele

Answer (score 0):

So converter o numero antes de salvar no banco de dados com a função: [`NumberFormatter::parseCurrency()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parsecurrency.php)

```
$formatter = numfmt_create('pt_BR', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
 $produto->custo1 = numfmt_parse_currency($formatter, $request->input('custo1'), "BRL");
```